# Cassandra Backup and Restore using EBS snapshot and NodeTool Snaphots

Tags: amazon-ec2, cassandra

I've a couple of questions regarding best approach to Backup/Restore Cassandra Cluster.

Background : I've a cluster running in EC2. It's nodes are configured like so:

Instance type : m3.medium
Storage : 50 GB Root Volume/100 GB another volume

After reading lot of documents and searching in few websites I understood that EBS Snapshots with Cassandra(nodetool) snapshots looks quite promising.

Questions: EBS also take the incremental snapshots and Nodetools also takes the snapshot then how does these two tools are different or are they same and is there any other better approach to backup cassandra cluster?

Please advice.

Comment: did u find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at Netflix's [Priam](https://github.com/Netflix/Priam) as a possible solution for creating backups for AWS deployments. It only seems to work with 2.0.x though, but might point you in the right direction.

Comment: I checked it out but it's not an option for us because we're using  version 2.1.8